# What are anonymous variables?

Tags: variables, programming-languages, anonymous

> A program variable is an abstraction of a computer memory cell or collection
>   of cells. Programmers often think of variable names as names for memory locations, but there is much more to a variable than just a name.

In this case, what is an anonymous variable?
What does the below statement mean?

> Variables without names are called anonymous variables.

Can you provide language specific examples for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, reference variable to const can be initialized by constant.
In this point, temporary variable is created in memory to grab the constant.

```
const int &ref = 3;
```

like this. so we can call this temporary variable to "anonymous variable".

Answer (score 2):

Variables are where you store you values. 'Variable Name' is the usually the easiest (and more human-like) way to locate your value.For example, if I am a variable, you can get my value by calling my name, and the combination of my value and my name is called 'variable'.
However, not all variables need a name.Sometimes you just use them once and don't need them anymore; and in that case, a name is unnecessary.

The example given by @BAE HA RAM is a telling one,in which case you don't need a name for the value but ref to it by a pointer(But still got a name for that pointer)..

There are also many other anonymous things, anonymous type, anonymous function and so on. Most of them are created to avoid too many meaningless names for the things that you only need to run once.

I'd like to know which language you are using, so more specific example can be given...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!